# Download Malware samples by searching hash values

Tags: malware, malware-detection, virus-scanning

I am conducting a research to download ransomware samples, in order to analyze them. The challenge lies in downloading the ransomware binaries.

I have gone through carious websites, as virusign, malshare and malwre and downloaded more than 60000,000 samples. Then, I used the av-class script (https://github.com/malicialab/avclass) to label the samples and extracted the ransomware ones. However, out of the 60,000 samples I only got 200 Ransomware.

Later on, I downloaded hashes of ransomware binaries from VT. The current challenge lies in how to download these hash samples. 
  - I cannot use VT since it requires private API
  - I used malware search script, but seems broken and out of support (https://medium.com/@unixbr/malwaresearch-a-command-line-tool-to-find-malwares-on-openmalware-org-53bafeadb5e2)

I was wondering the best approach to download Ransomware samples for the hash values I have.